# Trying to import notebook into other notebook using %run command

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am using EMR notebooks to build a data pipeline. When trying to import EMR notebook into other notebook using %run notebook.ipynb

Parent notebook is being invoked but when trying to access variables defined in parent notebook I am getting below Issue and it is happening when notebook's kernel is selected as 'PySpark' but when the kernel is Python it is working:
**
An error was encountered:
name 'username' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'username' is not defined
**

Import notebooks in EMR notebooks